# Java - inconsistent/undefined use of lists

Tags: java

I was working on a coding problem and ran into an issue where the code output strange things.
The operation was when I was trying to add an element to a `List<Integer>`, and then add that list to a `List<List<Integer>>`. The value of the final `List<Integer>` immediately varies after it is added to the parent list.

```
List<List<Integer>> c2 = sum(rs, target - i);
System.out.println(c2);

for (List<Integer> o : c2) {
    System.out.println(result);
    result.add(o);
    result.get(result.size()-1).add(i);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[]
[[1, 1]]
[[1]]
```

Output with new ArrayList<>() call:

```
[[1]]
[]
[[1, 1]]
[[1, 1]]
```

The same thing happens if you use a for loop instead of a a foreach.

However, if you initialize a `new ArrayList<>(o)` inside the `result.add()`, the issue vanishes.

Can someone explain what is going on here behind the scenes causing this unexpected behavior?

Complete Program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Solution()).combinationSum2(new int[]{1,1}, 2);
    }
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum2(int[] candidates, int target) {
        List<Integer> s = IntStream.of(candidates).boxed().map(i -> i).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

        return sum(s, target);

    }

    private List<List<Integer>> sum(List<Integer> candidates, int target) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (candidates.size() == 1) {
            if (candidates.get(0) == target) {
                System.out.println("found as single element");
                result.add(candidates);
            }
            return result;
        }
        
        Integer last = null;
        List<Integer> rs = new ArrayList<>(candidates);
        for (int i : candidates) {
            rs.remove(0);
            if (last != null && last == i)
                continue;
            if (i == target) {
                List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>(1);
                tmp.add(target);
                result.add(tmp);
            }

            List<List<Integer>> c2 = sum(rs, target - i);
            System.out.println(c2);
            for (List<Integer> o : c2) {
                System.out.println(result);
                result.add(o);
                result.get(result.size()-1).add(i);
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            last = i;
        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `result`? Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @Unmitigated As far as I can see in this code, the pointer to the location of `List` `o` does not change in between modifying the value and adding it to the list.

@Chris done, sorry.

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @tgdavies what is wrong with what is provided?

Comment: There is no runnable program in your question, just a snippet of code which doesn't compile.

Comment: @tgdavies is the jdoodle blocked or not working?

Comment: Code should be in the question, not external sites.

Comment: @tgdavies sorry. Thought that would clog up the question. Here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue is in this section:

```java
if (candidates.get(0) == target) {
    System.out.println("found as single element");
    result.add(candidates);
}
```

You did not make a copy of the `candidates` parameter, which is `rs` from the frame of the caller (see `List<List<Integer>> c2 = sum(rs, target - i);`). On the next iteration, `rs.remove(0)` will delete the first element from that `List`, which was added to the result, thus modifying it before the method returns.

Comment: How did the issue manifest before running this section again? The printlns are not at that point.

Comment: @A.Johnston The statement that produces the final line of output `[[1]]` is the second last line of your method: `System.out.println(result); return result;` The second last line of output (`[[1, 1]]`) comes from `System.out.println(result);` inside the loop.